# How to ship a phonegap 3.5 app with prepopulated sqlite database

Tags: database, sqlite, cordova

I am trying to build a cross platform mobile app using Cordova/Phonegap 3.5.

First, I am trying to create the Android version using Eclipse with Android SDK.

One of the requirements is that I want my app to be shipped with some database tables created and pre-populated with some data.

I have tried various things so far, but nothing seems to be working.

Here is what I have done so far:

1. Created a database and tables with data in them using the sqlite3 commandline utility on windows. As a result I have got my mydb sqlite database file.
2. I have placed this db file under the assets/databases folder, as suggested in many posts.
3. I used github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper to create the DB:

   public class MyDatabase extends SQLiteAssetHelper {
     private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "database_name";
     private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
     public MyDatabase(Context context) {
       super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
     }
   }
4. Within my main activity I simply invoke the above class, in order to ensure that this gets executed. Is this the right way?
5. In my HTML file, I am trying to open the database and do some operations with it, as given here: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.1.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage
6. As per the above documentation, the `window.openDatabase()` function call should return the existing sqlite database and give me a handle to work with it further.

But this does not seem to be happening. When I run my app, it does not give me any error on the LogCat console, but it does not find my pre-populated database either.

Notes

With Cordova 3.5, I am not using any external sqlite plugin, as it is supposed to be in-built in this version. Is this correct?

As a side note - How can I browse my Android device (Nexus 7 tablet) to actually verify that the database has been created?

Thanks so much for any help.

Comment: Cordova makes use of the browser based WebSQL API which is sqlite, but not native sqlite. You need to use one of the plugins to be able to make use of native sqlite.

Comment: thanks Dawsone. I tried to add the following plugin cordova plugin add https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin.git  , but it still does not seem to be picking my prepopulated DB.

Answer (score 1):

Though this question is old... thought it might help someone to post my solution - found in 2017. (Since PhoneGap has changed, older solutions may no longer work or be accepted on the Android and Apple app markets.) I worked on this problem for a long time - the issue about how to import a pre-populated database - which there are not alot of easy solutions for. I found the best - and currently just about the ONLY - solution to be LiteHelpers CORDOVA-SQLITE-EXT (https://github.com/litehelpers/cordova-sqlite-ext)

I have added this in to my app and it is working well. I had to switch away from PhoneGap though - and use CORDOVA - but it is working for me.

Comment: In January 2022 `corodva-sqlite-ext` still works. There is also https://github.com/an-rahulpandey/cordova-plugin-dbcopy that does just the copy part but I haven't tried it.

Comment: oh thanks for sharing this info!   I appreciate it cuz I might just be checking this out soon.